# PostgreSQL LAG function for market price data change in percent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a market price logging table over 300 columns system logs data for every 15 seconds.. 4 rows for every minute

| _id | the_datetime | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-12-26 19:05:00 | 0.25 | 36.50 | 15.12 |
| 2 | 2021-12-26 19:05:15 | 0.25 | 36.60 | 15.12 |
| 3 | 2021-12-26 19:05:30 | 0.21 | 36.12 | 15.20 |
| 4 | 2021-12-26 19:05:45 | 0.32 | 36.50 | 15.22 |
| 5 | 2021-12-26 19:06:00 | 0.35 | 36.25 | 15.23 |
| 6 | 2021-12-26 19:06:15 | 0.36 | 36.33 | 15.24 |
| 7 | 2021-12-26 19:06:30 | 0.36 | 36.50 | 15.36 |

for colum1

```
SELECT _id,
       column1 ,
       LAG(column1 ,12) over (partition by _id order by _id desc)as colum3min
FROM the_table
order by _id desc
```

I need to check for every columnX price change for every 3 minutes is price change is higher than %0.5. For every row insert..

I tried to write a LAG function SQL but it doesn't worked.

can anyone help me to write me this sql for postgresql?

Comment: With a slight design change, you could do this for all items at once with one query.  You would need to add an item_id column and insert each item separately.  Inserting one row with ~300 items (1 per column) can be inconvenient/costly to process.  Then you would simply `PARTITION BY item_id` in your `LAG` calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't `partition by _id`, and you `should order by "the_datetime"`.

```
with u as
(SELECT _id,
       column1 ,
       LAG(column1, 12) over (order by "the_datetime") as column3min
FROM the_table)
select * from u
where column1 / column3min >= 1.005 or column3min / column1 >= 1.005
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=08a0fba2d93fd30a50ba8631052a5c48): I added some entries to show it's working.

Comment: The link to the fiddle doesn't work; please fix it.

Comment: @YevgeniyKosmak oh yeah sorry. Fixed!

Comment: saved the day thanks a lot ! my friend..

Comment: @BurakOZLER welcome to Stack Overflow! Please feel free to choose the answer as correct if it helped you.